# Read API Response Messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have Developed **ASP.net Core Web API & Web APP** Which are in the same solution but different projects.

in the API I have some validations/checking as you may call.

e.g: if user email already exists, the API returns 'Email alreday in use' like this

```
 bool EmailExists = dbContext.Users.Any(u => u.Email == user.Email);
 if (EmailExists)
 {
    return new JsonResult("Email Address already taken!, Try a differen Email");
 }
```

and so on. in some cases I may need to check multiple columns one a time, (eg: UserName, Email, TellNum)

This is an example of calling the API in the MVC

```
       using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseAPIUrl);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("Users", user);

            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
               //in here I want check the `Res` and if it contains the returned messages, I want to display them by assigning it to `TempData[infoMsg]`
               // else some something(register user)
            }
            // Check the returned JsonResult messages here if statusCode is ultered eg: BadRequest
        }
```

My Question is how can I display these types of response messages in razor view in the MVC(Web App). in PostMan its workin, returning the response messages in body.

I did a lot of research about this but couldn't come to conclusion. I also cantacted some Devs I know(not `.NET`) and they said use JavaScript to call your API, which means I have to change almost everything I have done so far.

I aslo tried ultereing the statuCode to something like `BadRequest` in the API(if Email exists) in which case it will be checked outside the `if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)` of the Httpclient.

any help or direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should return a http error and a body containing some data about it eg field and message to your mvc controller. That could be a 422 error or whatever you like really since it's effectively internal and just coming back to the mvc controller.

The controller can then add any such error to modelstate and you can use the razor model "client" validation mechanism to show the error associated with a field.

This is therefore using the same mechanism used for attribute validation in the controller where you'd do

```
 if (!ModelState.IsValid)
```

This is air code but will hopefully give you the idea.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PostUpdate(User u)
{
// call service and await response

var response = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(posturi, u);
var returnContent = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ReturnContent>();
if (response.Result != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
     ModelState.AddModelError(returnContent.FieldName,returnContent.Error); 
     return Page();
}
// etc
```

You will want a more sophisticated checking on errors of course and check you get the body you're expecting.

Maybe you just hard code the field and error message if there's only one possibility.  Maybe work with an array of fields and errors if there could be numerous validation fails.

Comment: Maybe I should use a model like `APIMsg` with one property then set the message and return it.

Comment: What you return is the http response body as I suggested, @Abdifatah the status is a header. The body could be anything you can serialise. A class which contains an array of another class which has property and error message is a fairly common pattern where there's validation requires a database call.